# Replace leading and trailing commas as well as duplicate commas between words in a string

Tags: java, regex

I am using the `.replaceAll()` function in java and want to use a expression in it to achieve the bellow result.

Input:`-,,2000,,399,600,,,678,,`

Output:`-2000,399,600,678`

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=\\d)(,){2,}(?=\\d)|\\b,+\\B|\\B,+\\b
```

You can use this and replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eB8xU8/7